# Two seperate click event in single button using wpf

Tags: wpf

Button Control Template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="status">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="60" Height="60"  Background="#8eb548">
            <Button Content="Ad" Width="20" Height="40" Margin="7 0 0 0" Click="btn1_click"/>
            <Button Content="Ch" Width="20" Height="40" Margin="5 0 0 0" Click="btn2_click"/>
        </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Button

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource status}" Width="60" Height="60"/>
```

I want two different button click event in single button. thats why i used two buttons for my button control template. Is that right way to do it? or is there any other way?

Comment: It's probably more helpful to tell us why you want to have two click events in a single button. We are more likely to give you a better solution that works properly and is more elegant if you tell us this.

Comment: i want to navigate to separate new window when i click those two buttons..

Comment: Dont use `Click`-Event. Use the Command-Property of the `Button` and bind it as you need. Simple as that

Comment: actually i used command..

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways of doing this :

1. `Btn.Click += Btn_Click;`

   `Btn.Click += Btn_Click_1;`
2. Handle `Click` event of both inner and outer Buttons.

   ```
    <Button x:Name="Btn" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
       <Button Content="Button" />
    </Button>
   ```
3. Handle `Button.Click` at container level along with `Button` level.

   ```
   <Grid ButtonBase.Click="Grid_Click_1">
        <Button x:Name="Btn" Content="Press" Click="Btn_Click_2"/>
   </Grid>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have a single button and bind it to a command. Change the command parameter as per your wish. Maybe you want 1 functionality to happen when the button content is `Ch` and another functionality to occur when the button content is `Ad`. So pass the button as command parameter. You can even pass the button content as command parameter.

```
<Button Content="{Binding BtnContent}" Width="20" Height="40" Margin="5 0 0 0" Command={Binding BtnClick} CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content}" />
```

For xaml : 
You could just check the button content and run the 2 functionalities.
For eg :

```
if(btn1.Content == "Ch")
{
    //Do functionality for Ch
}
else if(btn1.Content == "Ad")
{
    //Do functionality for Ad
}
```

Comment: if i pass button content as command parameter, how to access that button name "btn1" in viewmodel??

Comment: Bind the button content to a property in view model like this `Content="{Binding BtnContent}"` . If you're following the MVVM pattern it would be very simple.